# incosistent relative frequency outputs with summarise and mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to compute relative frequency of a group of values with respect to the remaining groups. For example, compute the relative frequency of `gear==3` in `am==0`. I have computed using the following way.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  select(am, gear) %>% 
  group_by(am, gear) %>% 
  summarise(N = n()) %>%
  group_by(am) %>% 
  mutate(freq = N / sum(N))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
# Groups: am [2]
# 
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#     am  gear     N      freq
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>     <dbl>
# 1     0     3    15 0.7894737
# 2     0     4     4 0.2105263
# 3     1     4     8 0.6153846
# 4     1     5     5 0.3846154
```

The above output is as expected. However, I would like the `freq` values as a new column in original dataset with same values. I tried the below approach for calculating the count `Ǹ` and then relative frequency `freq`.

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(am, gear) %>% 
  group_by(am, gear) %>% 
  mutate(N = n()) %>%
  group_by(am) %>% 
  mutate(freq = N / sum(N))

# Source: local data frame [32 x 4]
# Groups: am [2]
# 
# # A tibble: 32 x 4
#      am  gear     N       freq
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>      <dbl>
# 1     1     4     8 0.08988764
# 2     1     4     8 0.08988764
# 3     1     4     8 0.08988764
# 4     0     3    15 0.06224066
# 5     0     3    15 0.06224066
# 6     0     3    15 0.06224066
# 7     0     3    15 0.06224066
# 8     0     4     4 0.01659751
# 9     0     4     4 0.01659751
# 10     0     4     4 0.01659751
# # ... with 22 more rows
```

Now, it gives a different output. What might be the reason?

Comment: Well, `sum(N)` in summarize has less values to sum than mutate, hence the much smaller values in your second attempt. You can try `mutate(freq = N / sum(unique(N)))` in the last line but It's not very safe

Comment: `group_by(am)` doesn't do the trick in restricting it to count only in that group? `sum(unique(N))` misses genuine duplicates, I meant same frequent `am-gear` combinations. As the number increases, even the share of this value increases linearly. So, I assume it does not make difference in the relative frequency calculation.

Comment: It does. But your groups are larger now because are a result of mutate rather than summarise. The reason that it makes a difference in rel.freq. is because your `N` is the same in both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recalculate the N size for the am group as well:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(am, gear) %>% 
  group_by(am, gear) %>% 
  mutate(N = n()) %>% 
  group_by(am) %>% 
  mutate(freq = N / n())
```

This gets the expected results

Answer (score 3):

A better option would be `left_join` with the summarised output ('res')

```
mtcars %>%
        select(am, gear) %>%
        left_join(., res)
```

---

If we look at the `sum(N)` it is a bit larger value because there are more number of rows

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But, I basically want to know what went wrong there and understand. Personally, I do not want to create another object `res` for this operation.

Comment: @Prradep  Supppose there are 100 rows and we are summing the whole number of elements in the 2nd case for each group, but with the first approach there are only few rows

Comment: As the number increases, even the share of this value increases linearly. So, I assume it does not make difference in the relative frequency calculation.

Comment: No. Your `N` is still the same in both cases. So in one case you are doing `N / 3` and on the other `N / 10`... I think the safest way to go is to do a merge as akrun suggests

Comment: Is it possible to generate without the creation of a new object `res`?

Comment: @Prradep Yes, you can do `%>%right_join(., mtcars %>% select(am, gear))`.